# PHP GD image with 2 files

Tags: php, gd

Here is what im trying to do. Be advise im fairly new to `GD2`

I want to make an image out of 2 images this way;

A background rectangle filled with images no 1

After that i want to draw a `polygon` over it filled with another image.

What i have right now is the rectangle and the image in background.

I can draw the polygon but i cant figure out how to fill it with another image. it is filled in blue right now and i would like to fill it with another image.

Heres my code

```
$values = array(
            40,  50,  // Point 1 (x, y)
            20,  240, // Point 2 (x, y)
            60,  60,  // Point 3 (x, y)
            240, 20,  // Point 4 (x, y)
            50,  40,  // Point 5 (x, y)
            10,  10   // Point 6 (x, y)
        );

$image2 = imagecreatefromjpeg('test2.jpg');
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('test.jpg');

$bg   = imagecreatefromjpeg('test.jpg');

$fill = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);

// fill the background
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, 249, 249, $bg);

// draw a polygon
imagefilledpolygon($image, $values, 6, $fill);

// flush image
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

as you can see `imagepng()` render only `$image` how do i get it to render $image and $image2

Thanks all

Comment: Your header is wrong, should be `Content-type: image/png` when you're outputting a png image.

Comment: Yes but this is only a test page. its working no mather what header i give it. im focusing on getting 2 image to load into 1

Comment: You should still correct it. It's only three characters.

Answer (score 5):

You need to overlay the second image on top of the first.

```
$file1 = 'test.jpg';
$file2 = 'test2.jpg';

// First image
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file1);

// Second image (the overlay)
$overlay = imagecreatefromjpeg($file2);

// We need to know the width and height of the overlay
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($file2);

// Apply the overlay
imagecopy($image, $overlay, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
imagedestroy($overlay);

// Output the results
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: Haaaa!! this look like what im looking for. Thanks i like the word overlay =p

Comment: Thanks for this.  Just learning GD and it was a huge help for a snippet I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you torn `imagealphablending` off for Image2, draw an inverse of your polygon on Image2 with a color with alpha value: 0. Turn `imagealphablending` on. And then you can copy Image2 over Image1 (the background).

Comment: Does this mean  i have to draw the polygon myself into the image??Cuse i want to do something that dont need you to draw images The polygon coord would be given by the user by clicking on the images so it could change shape every time the user use the page

Comment: If the ccordinates matter and you want a new image *based on the coordinates* then you have to create it. Caching is an other story, you can save a filename which contains the coordinates, so once created the image can be served from disc for subsequent requests. - Although I may have misundertood your question.